# A saddle point problem for Poisson's equation

Tags: finite-element-method, poissons-equation

I want to prove the well-posedness of the following saddle point problem:
Given $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ , $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the problem of finding $(u,\lambda)\in H_{0}^{1}\times \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u(x)+\lambda=f(x) & x\in\Omega\\
\\
\displaystyle\int\limits_{\Omega} u(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\alpha
\end{cases}
$$
My problem is that this equation is similar to Poisson equation but I don't know what to do with $\lambda$: especially I have problem in writing the weak formulation and proving its well-posedness.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\lambda u(x)$ or just $\lambda$? Also is the domain bounded?